# Get cause of Multipeerconnectivity connection error

Tags: ios, iphone, multipeer-connectivity

I am using the MultipeerConeectivity framework to transmit data between two iOS devices. Sometimes the connection is not getting established even after the receiver accepts the invitation.

i.e `- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state` is called with state as `MCSessionStateNotConnected` for sender.

Is there any workaround to get the reason of the connection failure, like dangling wifi, not in range, etc? Any help is greatly appreciated.